# Python: Virtual environment is not actually loaded in Jupyter

Tags: python, pip, package

I installed the package `TTS` using the `--user` option and then in a virtual environment called `TTSenv`. When installing using the `--user` option, a different version of numpy had to be installed. When I run `import TTS.config` in the Python command line in the environment, I get no errors. However in the Jupyter Notebook when I switch to the `TTSenv` kernel and run `import TTS.config`, I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TTS.config

Running `!where python` in Jupyter returns

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

and doing the same in the Python CLI gives

> C:\Users\user\Desktop\patents\TTS\TTS\Scripts\python.exe
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

Here is the output of `sys.path` in CLI:

> ['', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python38.zip',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs', 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3', 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\TTS\TTS',
> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\patents\TTS\TTS\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\patents\TTS\TTS\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\patents\TTS\TTS\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\patents\TTS\TTS\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']

and here is its output in Jupyter:

> ['C:\Users\user\Desktop\TTS',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python38.zip',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib',  'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3',  '',
> 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
> 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions',
> 'C:\Users\user\.ipython']

So it seems that Jupyter is not running in the virtual environment even though the kernel name is shown as TTS.

Comment: Your question doesn't really contain enough details. What does `sys.path` contain when it works, and when it doesn't? Where is `TTS` installed in each case, and does that location also contain `tts.config`? Do you have the same version of `TTS` in both cases?

Comment: @tripleee Actually the problem is that Jupyter is not really run in the TTS environment. I correct the question

Comment: How is the `TTSenv` kernel defined? The output looks like you are not in a virtual environment at all, though the `sys.path` is different.

Comment: @tripleee It is installed using python -m ipykernel install --user --name=TTS

Comment: No I mean how is it set up inside Jupyter? The actual problem seems to be that you are trying to use it but you're not.